# What is the correct name for each slash-separated piece of a file/URL path?

Tags: path, terminology

What is a 'piece' of a path called? (Including folder names, file names, and stuff like `..` or `.`)

```
../foo/bar/baz
↑   ↑   ↑   ↑

or

https://example.com/foo/bar/baz
                     ↑   ↑   ↑
```

And does the terminology vary by OS or context?

Comment: In the context of MVC, the first is called the controller, the second is called the action.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The terminology varies by context. For most web sites and web applications, the entire path together is taken at once and called, unsurprisingly, **path**. This follows the standard set forth in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), though the *standard* is still loosely defined throughout the whole document.

For web applications that use parts of the uri as parameters to functions (such as [Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html)), those pieces are referred to as **segments**. The reasoning behind Codeigniter's naming convention is derived from the design of the application. Each segment has a purpose, and the purpose is not always to locate the page or function that a user is accessing. Some of the segments are used as parameters to functions just as one might use a query string to pass variables through the uri.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a **directory** which holds **subdirectory** and then use **parent** and **child**, to describe the relationship between a **subdirectory** and the directory in which it is cataloged. The top-most directory in such filesystem, which does not have a parent of its own, is called the **root** directory.